# Expand htmls tags in shiny DT table not working

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny

With the below code, I am trying to add plus button and expand it when clicked. But unfortunately, it is not working as expected. Can anyone please help here?

I think the issue here is adding scripts inside HTML tags to remove null values. If I remove the script tags, it is all working fine

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)
add_collapse_content <- function(x, id) {
  tagList(
    tags$button(
      "data-toggle" = "collapse",
      "data-target" = paste0("#", id),
      "+"
    ),
    div(
      "id" = id,
      "class" = "collapse",
      x
    )
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$table <- renderDT({
    pciris <-
      iris %>%
      mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
      rowwise() %>%
      mutate(
        plus_column =
          add_collapse_content(HTML("<body><div style=\"background-color:#cbe6ef; padding: .5em;text-align:center;\"><table><tr><td><b>Tag</b></td><td><b>Number of Reviews</b></td><td><b> Share of Reviews </b></td><td><b> Click for Reviews </b></td> <tr><td> null </td><td>' + d[50] + '</td><td>' + d[51] + '</td><td>' + d[52] + '</td></tr> <tr><td>' + d[45] + '</td><td>' + d[46] + '</td><td>' + d[47] + '</td><td>' + d[48] + '</td></tr></td></tr> </tr></table><script type='text/javascript'> document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((item) => {if (item.textContent.includes('null')) {item.parentElement.remove();}})</script></body></div></body>"),
                               id = paste0("pc_", rn)
          ) %>%
          as.character()
      ) %>%
      relocate(plus_column)
    
    datatable(pciris,
              escape = F,
              rownames = F, options = list(columnDefs = list(
                list(orderable = FALSE, className = "details-control", targets = c(0))
              ))
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: hi .. Can any experts help me here please